# Docusign Rest API login using api credentials

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

Docusign rest api examples works using the manual login to docusign. The user has to enter the username and password to continue using the api's, I am looking for the method use api based on api credentials from backend config for better user experience. Can someone help on this whether we can achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You can use JWT instead of Auth Code Grant. [JWT Tokens](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/) do not require user to login and it is useful for back-end processes and other programs that do not have UI for user to login.